# Glassfish PermGen Not Collecting

Tags: java, garbage-collection, glassfish, jvm, permgen

Today after many days of running without issue, my glassfish application started throwing OOM: PermGen messages. After a restart it worked for about an hour and then failed again for the same reason. When I attach jconsole or visual vm to the instance, I notice that PermGen allocation grows and never is collected. If I force a GC, the PermGen memory is collected correctly and it goes back to the same level repeatedly. If I leave the GC alone, it never occurs and PermGen repeatedly grows to the max and then crashes. Why would this happen, and why would this happen out of the blue?

```
java version "1.7.0_51" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```